# afterTextChange receiving always the same Editable instance

Tags: android, textwatcher, android-10.0, android-textwatcher

I faced an issue with a a custom `TextWatcher` in Android 10.

The issue was that our custom `TextWatcher` was keeping a reference to the `Editable` passed in as a parameter of `afterTextChanged`.

This reference was compared to the new `Editable` every time `afterTextChanged` is called.

Apparently, on Android 10, the `Editable` instance is always the same across `afterTextChanged` invocations.

This was not the case before Android 10, hence the issue and this question.

The following is a simplification of the implementation

```
class MyTextWatcher : TextWatcher {

  private var oldEditable: Editable? = null

  override fun afterTextChanged(newEditable: Editable) {

    // if this is Android 10, then the following is always true
    // (except when oldEditable == null)

    // If android < 10, this is always false, as there's 
    // always a different instance of Editable being passed.

    if (oldEditable == newEditable) {

    }else{

      oldEditable = newEditable // Hold to the new instance

    }
  }

  override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    ...
  }

  override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I understand the previous implementation might not be perfect, so I guess the questions are:

- Was the initial implementation flawed and we should never have assumed that the instance will always be different?
- Is the new behavior the expected and correct? or it is some sort of regression ?
- Is there any place where I can find documentation about this? This kind of framework changes are tricky to detect and would love to be on top of them.

Thanks